# sql query to show a range and account for missing numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a SQL query

```
SELECT 
    Group_Id, MIN(Rec_Number) as RecStart, MAX(Rec_Number) AS RecEnd
FROM
    Rec
WHERE
    Group_Id != '' 
GROUP BY
    Group_Id
ORDER BY 
    Group_Id
```

This produces the following kind of results.

```
92-2274 9222740001  9222740004
92-2275 9222750001  9222750026
etc...
```

However if record 3 is missing (in the first row for instance) the query obviously doesn't account for it. What I am trying to do is the following

```
92-2274 9222740001  9222740002
92-2274 9222740004  9222740018
92-2275 9222750001  9222750016
92-2275 9222750018  9222750026
etc...
```

So essentially each time the script sees a record missing inside the group it starts a new line whilst staying inside the group before iterating on the next group. The `group_Id` is of course the first 6 digits of the `rec_Number`

I would also like to do this as well

```
92-2274       0001        0002
92-2274       0003        0004
```

Or even trim it to and remove the leading 0's as well if possible I know about using `Right (Rec_Number, 4)` however as this is a float the automatic convert to string seems to be messing something up as I get +009 is many columns so I assume I need to cast first or something. This particular function I could do it Excel after the fact I guess but I'm sure SQL could do it if the guy writing the query was a DBA and not a bumbling server admin (that's me!)

So is there a way of doing that in SQL also I must warn you that the standard CTE or using functions such as row number don't work as this is SQL Server 2000 - yes it is that old!

Hence me struggling to find posts on Stack Overflow that apply. Many of them start with the WITH keyword which means I can't use any of those to start with!

I think I am needing an IF ELse kind of block but I am not sure what kind of method I can use to get the query to create a new row each time it hits a missing concurrent number in the group range.

The final output will show me the ranges of records in each group whilst highlighting the missing ones via a new line each time.

Comment: SQL server 2000 but I am using SSMS 2014 the database is MS SQL 2000

Comment: Upgrade your database.  Your are using a database that has been unsupported since April 2013.  Time to upgrade!

Comment: I wish I could trust me but I don't have that option right now as its not my software.

Comment: if record 3 is missing, shouldn't your second row of 92-2274 start with 4?

Comment: Also, why is there a break in the 2275 group between 16 and 17?  is 17 missing?

Comment: @SimonSpencer . . . I should also point out that people who know the answer to this question aren't going to be as willing to dig through memory or documentation to remember what SQL Server 2000 supports and doesn't support.  It has been relegated to history at this point.

Comment: Sorry Beth that is a typo the second row should start with 4 and the fourth row should have 17 missing and indeed start with 18

Comment: @Gordon I realize this is an annoying problem and under 2008 sql server and above it would be far easier to solve and indeed some answers could be gained from similar examples on the net. Are you suggesting that I may be better exporting the results I can get to something else say Excel and process further there.

Comment: @Beth Ok just edited that thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @SimonSpencer I think you'll find your solution [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: @Beth That looks ideal I will mess with that. Thanks Beth I had spotted an islands link that is newer but disregarded it as it was sql 2008 or newer. So this link may well be perfect

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, this should work :

```
RIGHT ( CAST ( MIN (Rec_Number) as Decimal(10)), 4)
```

It will only keep the last 4 characters of your number.

Comment: RIGHT ( CAST ( MIN (Rec_Number) as Decimal(10)), 4)

Comment: Thanks for your code though I think the Column is a float so it got out of range I guess bizarrely I had to use

Comment: RIGHT ( CAST ( MAX (Rec_Number) as Decimal(11)), 4) on the max line for the same reason!?

Comment: If the column is of type float, you may get data loss issues at some point. However, did you try any float to int conversion ? Is CEILING supported by your current MS SQL version ?

Comment: Yes I can use Ceiling I think just tried and it seems to recognize that